# Limit Firebase Auth Signup when Quota is reached

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

We are building a mobile app and use Firebase Phone Auth. Since we are students and do not want to exceed the free tier of 10k signups per month we want to limit it in our app.

We are going to use Firebase Dynamic Links to allow users to signup. So a user must scan a QR code which will be checked in the app if it is still valid. But we also want to check there if we already reached the limit of for example 8k signups this month (8k to be sure :)).

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve what you need is by creating custom tracker on client side incrementing tracker value when user passes after QR code verification.

Also just for info there is a daily limit 50sms/day with phone auth, you can check more info [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/limits#phone-auth).

Comment: We have the Blaze plan but do not want to exceed the 10k month signups

Comment: After second reading of docs this limits are for both plans, sorry for the mistake.